# 80s or possibly early 90s anime with a race of giant caterpillar things

Tags: story-identification, anime

Might not be anime (or just Japanese animation, I don't know the difference).

I don't remember much from this movie other than a brief glimpse of an aerial view of the caterpillars moving like a herd. And the hero (or heroine) who sacrifices him/herself by jumping, or throwing herself/himself in the way of gun/laser fire. There were quick-cut shots of the laser/bullets hitting the character. Then (I believe) the caterpillars somehow heals the hero/heroine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like "[Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nausica%C3%A4_of_the_Valley_of_the_Wind_(film))" a Japanese animation from 1984. There are giant caterpillar-like animals, shooting and there is a heroine being resuscitated by the caterpillars, though that follows the heroine being run over.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Beat me to it by a minute, +1. Also at some point Nauusica does get shot and gets seriously hurt, not long before being run over by the Ohmu.